# Xamarin Android - How to get SetDataAndType to populate the right apps? CreateChooser app selection does not read my "File Manager" app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-intent

Currently I have a button "Go to Folder" and it's suppose to do exactly that: go to intended folder.  I am using A OnPlus 3 (7.1) and verizon droid (4.4) as my debug phones.  When I click on the button three responses happen:

[One Plus 3]

intent 1,2 - just give me the "no apps can perform this action."

I find this odd because I have the default app that comes with OP3 called File Manager, and it should be read by intent 1 and 2...I think.

intent3 - On the OP3 the intent3 (attached at bottom) goes to "recent" folder, and when you press the "hamburger" menu, it gives the "open from option". I then would have to navigate to specified folder.  This method does not work.

[Verizon Droid]

I currently have no specific third party app installed, and wanted to see what options android would provide with I used these same intents.

Intent 1,2,3 - all give me the "no apps can perform this action."

Why is this?

---

Code

```
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
        Intent intent3 = new Intent(Intent.ActionGetContent);


        global::Android.Net.Uri uri = global::Android.Net.Uri.Parse(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath + "//ID/");

        intent.SetDataAndType(uri, "application/file");
        intent2.SetDataAndType(uri, "resource/file");
        intent3.SetDataAndType(uri, "resource/file");


        Forms.Context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(intent1, "Choose App Intent1"));
        Forms.Context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(intent2, "Choose App Intent2"));
        Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent3);
```

[Intent1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4VO3.gif)

Comment: I really don't understand what you means, you want open a folder with an app?

Comment: I'm trying to go to a folder when I click a button.  No method above works.